# Get JavaScript prompt data and convert it into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a school project involving web design, and I am stuck with getting my JavaScript prompt data to be linked to a button input field, so that I can send it to PHP and into a phpMyAdmin database.

The following is what I have done:

```
  <!-- Final Design -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" >
     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Bob Ross and the hunt for the perfect mountain</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header> <h1>Bob Ross and the hunt for the perfect mountain</h1> </header>
    <div class="container">
    <nav>

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active"  href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="play_nav" onclick="GetName_LoadPage()">Play (push twice)</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="Pages/Help/Help.html">F.A.Q/Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="greeting">
                <img src="Images/clorox-chan.png" id="clorox_can" alt="clorox chan" width=450px height=550px>
                <form method="post" id="username_form" action="db_connection.php">
                    <input class="button" id="start_button" name="person" type="button" onclick="GetName_LoadPage()" value="Go to game (push twice)">
                        <br>
                    <input class="button" id="help_button" type="button" onclick="location.href='Pages/Help/Help.html';" value="Help/F.A.Q" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        function GetName_LoadPage() {
            var txt;
            var person = prompt("Please enter your username:", "Bob Ross-chan");    
            if (person == null || person == "") {
                txt = "You have canclled the prompt.";
            } 
            else {
                txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
            }


            document.getElementById("start_button").onclick = function () {
                window.location.href = "Pages/Intro/Intro.html";
            };


            document.getElementById("play_nav").onclick = function () {
                window.location.href = "Pages/Intro/Intro.html";
            };      
        }

        function goToHelpPage() {

            document.getElementById("help_button").onclick = function () {
                window.location.href = "Pages/Help/Help.html"
            };

    }   

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to get your `txt` value from the `prompt` into the PHP back-end. The most common way to do that is with an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest) (a.k.a. AJAX, "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML"). Here's an example using `POST`:

```
function sendTextToServer(txt) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://myserver.com/myfile.php");
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("txt", txt);
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // state DONE, status OK
      console.log(xhr.responseText); // your request has been received, do what you want with the result here.
    }
  });
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

If you were to paste this function definite above `GetName_LoadPage` in your example, then you would probably call `sendTextToServer(txt);` just below `txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";`, within that same `else {}` block.

Since I chose to use `POST` here, it would show up in PHP in `$_POST['txt']`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was wondering shouldnt the variable person by in the place of "txt" in the line: formData.append("txt", txt);  ?

Comment: Sure, you can do `formData.append("person", person);`, and similarly for whatever data you want to send to the back-end. Your code prepared `txt` and had not yet used it, so I guessed that's what you wanted to send.

Comment: I have changed it to formData.append("person", person);  But do I need to change the parameter from "txt" to person ? Sorry for bothering you, and thanks again.

Comment: Whatever you call it (it's up to you), just make it consistent with the back-end. If it's a name, I would call it name.